# ORM map a variable to a SQL query within Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I've got a simple pojo which is filled thanks to hibernate. I would like to see a variable from this pojo being mapped to a very specific SQL query and I wonder if this is possible to create such a mapping in the hibernate.xml file ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way in pure JPA to do that. The best would be to use [Hibernate's @Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785) annotation, on which you can specify a "SQL Fragment" that should be used to get the field's data.

Comment: That seems nice, is it possible to do this in the xml mapping file rather than as an annotation ?

Comment: Yes, see 5.1.4.2 on the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-property

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some thing like this

```
String sql = "SELECT a.id As id, CONCAT(a.firstName,' ',a.lastName) AS advisorName from tableAdvis";

List<CollectionReport> collectionList = (List<CollectionReport>) getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CollectionReport.class)).list();
```

Here is my CollectionReport POJO looks like

```
public class CollectionReport {

    private BigInteger id;
    private String advisorCode;
    private String advisorName;    
   //Getter & Setter

}
```

ResultTransformer will get query result and based on property name in POJO, it assigns values to it.